# Preact map array of data

Tags: reactjs, preact

I am building a component that will list dynamically the next three meeting date. Inside the component, when I console.log the props variable its mapping each character in the array. The first line in the console log is what is being returned from the getMeetingDates function

[image]

Here is the render

```
render() {
    return (
        <div class={style.sidebar}>
            <div className="sidebar-sections">
                <h3>Next Meeetings</h3>
                {this.getMeetingDates().map(date => <MeetingDates {...date} />)}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are spreading a string as prop:

```
<MeetingDates {...date} />
```

say `date` is `foo` or whatever, the above will mean

```
<MeetingDates f o o />
```

Instead, pass `date` as prop:

```
this.getMeetingDates().map(date => 
    <MeetingDates date={date} />
)
```

Comment: This is a lovely answer <3